# ggplot2: Additional lines occuring after changing color even if both col variables are similar

Tags: r, ggplot2, line

I have a problem that when changing the color of the lines in my graph, additional lines are occurring and I have absolutely no idea where they originate from.

First, by running the code with `col = origin` the graph looks as it should. After changing to `col = density`, the graph looks as it should but additional lines or whatever it is are occurring. It looks like some linear functions? I have no idea it does not match the data frame at all.

```
ggplot(data=Sediment, aes(x = m))+
      geom_path(aes(y = substance, col = origin))+
      labs(y = "substance", x = "Distance [m]")+
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,3 , by = 0.25))+
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,250))

ggplot(data=Sediment, aes(x = m))+
        geom_path(aes(y = substance, col = density))+
        labs(y = "substance", x = "Distance [m]")+
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,3 , by = 0.25))+
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,250))
```

[image]

[image]

Graph 1 is the correct one, and graph 2 the one with the additional lines

col variables are both characters.

hopefully someone has an idea concerning that problem...

Comment: It's easiest if you provide some of your data via the output of `dput`. So, you can type `dput(df)` into the console, then paste the output into your question. You can also use `head`, so that you only give part of the dataframe (e.g., `dput(head(df, 30))`

Comment: Try with `geom_path(aes(y = substance, col = density, group = origin))`. This way you get lines by origin but colored by density. Otherwise all lines belonging to the same density get connected, i.e. you get connecting lines.